# visual basic 6, refreshing or start with VS

Tags: vb.net, vb6

i use to program a lot with VB 6 from Dec 1997 to Jan 2002 
simple exe program like retrive a URL, edit registry, etc

now in 2016, should i start with VB6 or VS ?

i want to make a simple program that will restore internet explorer/chrome/firefox start page, patch registry (which would pull from my server)

Reason: i manage a lot of computers for my school, and spyware, is becoming a fulltime job.

Comment: Neither. Learn PowerShell: for the types of task you list, it fits the bill perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Go for `VB.net` since `VB6` is no longer supported by Microsoft and some latest OS. There will be a learning curve to study the latest concepts but, I'm sure it will be easier for you with your `VB6` knowledge.

Comment: i installed vb6 in win7/64, i was able to make a textbox value from a url testfile. . i installed 2015 studio.,, , fresh and spent almost 40 hours getting no where... so much bloatware, addons, errors,  is there a much lighter solution? if i can use vb to write to 32/64 bit registry iwill just use it..

Comment: People are using VB6 to write new programs every day, both on Windows 10 and for Windows 10.  Ignore these trolls.

Answer (score 1):

You will serve yourself much better in the long run by going down the VB.Net route. It really is much more powerful, and easier once you get over the initial learning hump. Once you get used to the VS IDE you will hate having to go back to the VB6 IDE - trust me.

I see from some of your responses that you are getting a bit stuck. If you post a question with the problems you are having, then you will get the right pointers to set you going.

Simple code to read a textfile from a URL, and display it in a Textbox:

```
Dim myAddress As String = "http://www.someserver.com/sometextfile.txt"
Dim myClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim myReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myClient.OpenRead(myAddress))
textbox1.Text = myReader.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: thank you, i installed VS 2015, got a truck load of erros, it had to install about 35 programs.. is tehre a light weight option? ..

Comment: also in VB,net how can i sent those values to a registry key, i searched and got about 50 pages of results so many different ways i wouldnt know where to begin i would like a light weight one where i dont have to install thirdpatty modules, classes, ocx;s etc. thank you Slugsie

Comment: The VS installer should install and configure everything correctly, you shouldn't have to install anything else. If you start with the recommended setup options you should be good to go as soon as it finishes. The 'light weight' option is to untick stuff you don't need (like C++, F#), but don't go unticking everything until you know what it is.

Comment: As for getting a value from the registry:

Comment: [Oops] My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<softwarename>,"<setting value>")

Comment: Type 'WebClient' not defined..  in VB6 i would just add a webbox .. so confusing in VS

Comment: thanks for registry.getvalue but got a truck load of errros do i have to define anything?

Comment: didnt work, microsoft help actually was simple this time     Dim readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp", "Name", Nothing)
    MsgBox("The value is " & readValue)

Comment: how can i load the registry entry from textbox?

Comment: example My.Computer.Registry.SetValue all values from textbox (web))

Comment: i spent 5 hours trying to build an exe file, VB 6 was so easy, i have checked everywhere for the exe from WIndowsapplication1 ...

Comment: You are going to need to give a few details about the errors, just saying you had 'a truck load' doesn't help us help you. I think you need to take the time to organise what you are trying to achieve, and what you've tried, and what errors you've got. Then post another question. This stuff is fairly basic stuff, and the MSDN documentation is pretty good and has all you need.

Comment: You need to add an Imports System.Net at the start to use a WebClient. The IDE will actually suggest this sort of thing as a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic has moved on since VB6 to a much superior, better performing and more powerful object oriented language. The grounding you have in VB6 will give you a leg up to learn VB.NET. I wouldn't waste my time going back to VB6. The time and energy you spend refreshing your knowledge of VB6 would be far better spent on learning VB.NET.

Comment: i installed vb6 in win7/64, i was able to make a textbox value from a url testfile. . i installed 2015 studio.,, , fresh and spent almost 40 hours getting no where... so much bloatware, addons, errors,  is there a much lighter solution? if i can use vb to write to 32/64 bit registry iwill just use it..

Comment: According to this there should be no problem https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-compatibility-vs

Comment: I am running VS 2013 Pro on Win7 64-bit and it works just fine

Comment: is there a lightweight VS? would vs 2008 be ok to run   Dim myAddress As String = "http://www.someserver.com/sometextfile.txt"
Dim myClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim myReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myClient.OpenRead(myAddress))
textbox1.Text = myReader.ReadToEnd

Comment: where do you even SAVE the project. i can only save the forms.. this is stupid ,...